# Ember CLi SC is not defined when using css animation

Tags: javascript, variables, ember.js, jshint

I have a music component in an ember application using SoundCloud API, i have recently added a css animation with Font-awesome. See [codepen](http://codepen.io/jasonwhite1976/pen/myoXGm)

This is my markup

```
<div class="gears">
    <i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-fw small"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-cog fa-counter fa-fw big"></i>
</div>
```

After that my music component stopped working in chrome and  JS hint is giving me a 'SC' is not defined here

```
    return SC.stream(favoritePath, {
        whileplaying: function() {
            return self.set('currentFavoritePosition', this.position);
        },
        onbufferchange: function() {
            return self.set('isBuffering', this.isBuffering);
        },
        onfinish: function() {
            self.set('isPlaying', false);
            if (self.get('nextFavorite') != null) {
                return self.send('selectFavorite', self.get('nextFavorite'), index);
            }
            self.set('favorite.artwork_url', nextFavorite.artwork_url);
        }
```

In Safari and Firefox there is no problem, the music component is working.

I read that there is an issue about troubles of identifying this kind of global objects by JSHint, but i don't know if there is a connection with my case and why this happened after this animation and only in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Like you mention, JSHint is complaining that you are referring to the `SC` global variable but JSHint doesn't know where it was defined. See http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies/#toc_globals-provided-by-javascript-assets on how to fix that.

It's strange that it doesn't work on Chrome specifically, have you cleared the cache?

Comment: Yes i have also cleared the cache, but it does not make difference

Comment: I have also add   "undef": false, and   "unused": false in my .jshintr to remove the error but the issue is still present